# My Python code to web scrape and download five images is not working.. Using Blender(3D) as IDE

Tags: python, google-chrome, web, web-scraping

I am running this code too web scrape and download 5 images from Google: what's supposed to happen is after I run the code, a Chrome web browser is supposed to come up and the code is supposed to cause mouse click on an image and then download it and then Scroll down to another image mouse click that and download it etc, up to five times. What happens in this code is the Chrome browser comes up for a second closes and nothing else happens...though code doesn't throw up any Python errors.

I am using blender 3D modeling software as my IDE because I hope to make a Blender add on(a Blender add-on is kind of like an extension in Google Chrome it's a small piece of software that you install into Blender to increase its functionality) in the future using Python code. Which is the reason for the extra import lines at the top of my code...

One relevant item is that I get this warning:

E:\GLOBAL ASSETS\SCRIPTING\Web Scraping Images\web-scraper.blend\web-scraper.py:21: DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object

this is the only other piece of information that is in my console after I run the code:

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:52643/devtools/browser/ea448f70-0066-4d50-bfb8-8671528789b8

any help on this would be appreciated

```
import bpy
import subprocess
import sys
import os
import cv2
import random
from random import randrange
from PIL import Image #make sure both pil from c:\users\mjoe6\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python310\site-packages is in blender pip3.exe folder
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import requests
import io
import time

# path to python.exe
python_exe = os.path.join(sys.prefix, 'bin', 'python.exe')
py_lib = os.path.join(sys.prefix, 'lib', 'site-packages','pip')


PATH = "E:\\GLOBAL ASSETS\\SCRIPTING\\Web Scraping Images\\chromedriver.exe"
wd = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

def get_images_from_google(wd, delay, max_images):
    def scroll_down(wd):
        wd.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
        time.sleep(delay)
        
        url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=cats+2019+IMDb&sxsrf=ALiCzsZmBIp-JZmZv23v6ORoc0VL2NRuxg:1654543304286&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiRjquPxpn4AhUymo4IHbC6Cx0Q_AUoAnoECAEQBA&biw=1536&bih=714&dpr=1.25#imgrc=ixH-uoDQFN_gpM"
        wd.get(url)
        
        image_urls = set()
        while len (image_urls) < max_images:
            scroll_down(wd)
            thumbnails = wd.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "Q4LuWd")
            for img in thumbnails[len(image_urls):max_images]:
                try:
                    img.click()
                    time.sleep.delay
                except:
                    continue    
                images = wd.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "n3VNCb")
                for image in images:
                    if image.get_attribute('src') and 'http' in image.get_attribute('src'):
                        image_urls.add(image.get_attribute('src'))
                        print(f"Found {len (image_urls)}")
        return image_urls
        
def download_image(download_path, url, file_name):
    try:
        image_content = requests.get(url).content
        image_file = io.BytesIO(image_content)
        image = Image.open(image_file)
        file_path = download_path + file_name
        with open(file_path, "wb") as f:
            image.save(f, "PNG")
        
        print("Success")
    except Exception as e:
        print('FAILED -', e)    


urls = get_images_from_google(wd, 1, 5)
print(urls)
wd.quit()
```

Comment: Sorry for the off-topic but Blender as an IDE sounds too cool to me :-) I imagine that [Power Mode](https://github.com/codeinthedark/awesome-power-mode) support should be out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 0):

Error could be in these lines,

```
                images = wd.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "n3VNCb")
```

should change like

```
                images = wd.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "iPVvYb")
```

also in this line

```
                if image.get_attribute('src') and 'http' in image.get_attribute('src'):
```

should change http with https,

```
                 if image.get_attribute('src') and 'http' in image.get_attribute('src'):
```